# Nexus container not starting up

Tags: linux, docker, sonarqube, nexus

Facing this error as i check my resource utilization on server is high but after fixing it giving this error.Can any body suggest how to fix this ?
Nexus docker container not starting up and the same time sonarqube container down too

ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.orient.restore.RestoreServiceImpl - Failed transition: NEW -> STARTED
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/nexus-data/db/component' with mode=rw
DB name="component"

Comment: I found this to fix :java -jar /opt/sonatype/nexus/lib/support/nexus-orient-console.jar
 
# Replace xxx with db name (the one which face the issue
CONNECT PLOCAL:/opt/sonatype/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/component admin admin
REBUILD INDEX *
REPAIR DATABASE --fix-graph
REPAIR DATABASE --fix-links
REPAIR DATABASE --fix-ridbags
REPAIR DATABASE --fix-bonsai
DISCONNECT  But container get exit not giving me enough time to execute it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question and comment, looks like the data might be corrupt. You can either

1. Use a different, temporary image to copy the directory over back to the host so you can run the java -jar command on the host
2. Use the AdoptOpenJdk Java image with the Nexus console jar and run the command directly on the directory.

The first might be safer because you are taking a copy of your data rather than running code on the original data.

Example for 1:
docker run ubuntu -v 
docker cp ubuntu:/nexus-data/db/component